# How to deploy wix installer package aspx from TFS automatically

Tags: iis, tfs, wix, web-deployment, autodeploy

Tfs builds succesfully .msi prepared for installation and then deployed manualy taken from TFS website as MSI with couple of configurations files(these run installer for different enviroment) - in installation process i need to install them on ISS there To make this process automatic - now i got no idea of which direction to go first - i read briefly something about using remote call on target machine, i assume i would need to somehow get installation on target server and then run .msi remotely with particular settings.Before i start to do this, anyone would add any comment?

Comment: Don't deploy software from your build process. Use a tool designed for automating and managing releases.

Answer (score 0):

You should look to Release Management that comes with TFS and VSO. You can use this to automate the deployment of your website. You might even want to drop the MSI option as unessesary as you move forward with automated deployments.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Here is an example of deploying a website. You can of course just cipy your msi and run it.

Comment: Maybe they are selling the application and need it to be packaged.  The MSI is fine, just call it from Release Management and pass in proper parameters to the SQL.